# Why do I need the ChromeDriver in Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

This code works well except that it is really slow.
I don´t use the ChromeDriver. Just the normal Chrome Browser on my Mac.
Why do I have to download the ChromeDriver?
It doesn´t speed up the code execution. I've already tried that.

Also:
Why do I have to close the driver at the end of my programm with `driver.close()`?
The browser closes automatically when the code is finished.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know about the Mac, but on Windows if you do not issue `driver.quit()`, the driver process you create will remain even after your program terminates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your code is perfectly fine.**

`selenium version > 4.12.0`

There is **no need** to download the chromedriver manually,

Selenium's new in-built tool Selenium Manager will automatically download and manage the drivers for you.

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/
https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/status_of_selenium_manager_in_october_2023/

You do not have to use `driver.close()` with the above code.

Answer (score 1):

ChromeDriver is necessary for communication between Selenium and the Chrome browser. While it's true that downloading the ChromeDriver doesn't necessarily speed up the execution of your code, it is a critical component for Selenium to interact with the browser. Without ChromeDriver, Selenium won't be able to control the Chrome browser.

Comment: Thank you but it works without the ChromeDriver so I guess it`s inlcuded in Selenium